# getchar и буферизация кода клавиши Enter

Tags: c

Не понимаю логику поведения этого кода. Кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, подскажите.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    printf("a");
    getchar();
    printf("b");
    getchar();
    printf("c\n");

return 0;
}
```

Если просто нажимать Enter:
a
b
c

Если после вывода на экран первого символа,
набрать еще символ (или несколько), скажем 'd':

```
ad
bc
```

Как тут работает буферизация?

Comment: Попробуйте немного изменить программу, а именно, считывайте результат getchar() в переменную и **сразу  печатайте ее**. Уверен, вы сами все поймете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если кратко, то `getchar()` работает примерно следующим образом:

- Если в буфере есть непрочитанный символ, то она сразу удаляет его из буфера и возвращает.
- В противном случае:

  - Программа приостанавливается, пока не придут новые данные
  - Когда они придут, они заносятся в буфер (их может быть ); за один раз так может быть прочитано он 1 символа до размера буфера (обычно 4—8КиБ).
  - После этого первый символ из этих данных извлекается из буфера и возвращается пользователю.

При этом данные не читаются непосредственно с клавиатуры непосредственно программой: между ними стоят слои другого ПО, например, *драйвер клавиатуры*, *ОС*, *Драйвер терминала*, *Эмулятор терминала* и т.п.

Так вот, одна из таких программ накапливает пользовательские нажатия клавиш, в частности, она обрабатывает, нажатия на <kbd>Backspace</kbd> и занимается выводом определённых символов на экран. А когда пользователь нажмёт <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то эта программа отправит накопленный ввод уже прикладной программе.

---

> Если после вывода на экран первого символа, набрать еще символ (или
> несколько), скажем 'd':
>
> ```
> ad
> bc
> ```
>
> Как тут работает буферизация?

```
printf("a");   // Выводим 'a'

getchar();     // Буфер пуст ⇒ ожидаем ввод
               // Ввод пользователя отображается на экране во время ввода
               // Пользователь ввёл 2 символа: {'d','\n'}
               // Заносим их в буфер, извлекаем 'd', в буфере остаётся {`\n`}

printf("b");   // Выводим 'b'

getchar();     // Буфере не пуст ⇒ извлекаем символ '\n' и возвращаем его
               // т.к. в буфере были данные и запрашивать данные от пользователя 
               // было не надо, то и паузы, соответственно, нет

printf("c\n"); // Выводим 'с' и '\n'
```